# "I don't understand you" vs. "I'm not understanding you"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, present-tense, progressive-aspect

Which sentence is correct?

> - What are you talking about? I don't understand you.

or

> - What are you talking about? I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Both are OK, but the first is more likely in American English. I'd rarely use the second, if at all.

Comment: @rhetorician ell has been born and is a toddler no longer in the area51 womb.

Comment: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/grammarlogs/grammarlogs125.htm -- scroll down to Q4.

Comment: @Kris: Thanks for the correction. I was in a hurry, and I assumed (you know what they say about that) area51 was somehow the gateway to ELL. I even got into an endless loop of answering a question on Christianity SE without my being recognized as a full-fledged member in good standing! In future, I'll be more careful. Moreover, I need to find out more about area51!

Comment: Based on the new info (which is inconsistent with your original question) you provide, D is definitely incorrect!

Comment: (E) none of the above.  The correct sentence would be "What are you talking about?  I don't understand you"

Comment: I suppose "I'm not understanding you" is 'correct' but isn't as common

Comment: @Gus What's wrong with "What are you talking about? I'm not understanding you."

Comment: "I'm not understanding you." seems like Indian English.

Comment: @jboneca I think my second comment and yours were posted simultaneously.  To my American English ear, it sounds like something a non-native would say.

Comment: D is wrong and "I'm not understanding you." sounds perfectly OK in my English-speaking part of the world (US Midwest).

Comment: @Gus ah, gotcha.

Comment: The answer is, unfortunately, that this question was formed by someone either a) cruel or b) lazy.

Comment: @jboneca: I'm voting for either c) ignorant or d) parochial. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @TimLymington haha I was trying to stay a bit optimistic ;)

Answer (score 5):

Understand is a *stative* verb along with *like, remember, think, want*, etc. that is not normally used in the progressive form. This is why "*I'm not understanding*" is much less common than "*I don't understand*". However, as Huddleston in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p170) states:

> None of these (stative) verbs completely excludes the progressive. … The
>   progressive adds an element of tentativeness. … It is not so clear how
>   the politeness derives from the progressive. One factor is no doubt
>   length/complexity: polite formulations are often more complex than
>   ordinary ones.

The use of the progressive in the case of "*I'm not understanding you*" may also be interpreted here as implying that the failure to understand is a temporary state for which I, not you, bear the responsibility.

There is an extensive analysis of the various functions of the progressive (including tentativeness, politeness, deference, etc.) in [Levin: The progressive verb in modern American English](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/projects/verb-phrase/book/levin.pdf). Here is one extract:

> … the progressive is used as a device that reduces imposition on the
>   addressee.

Answer (score 1):

*meta*: This may not be an answer.

One source says:

> There are a number of verbs that can not be used in the Present Continuous. Th(ese are the) so-called **stative** verbs – verbs of state. (The) Present Continuous can only describe (an) action process that can start, pause or end.
>   (stative verbs:) *know, believe, **understand**, recognize, realize, suppose, deny, imagine …*  [emphasis mine]

However, I think *understand* is a verb that can be used in a 'continuous' (dynamic) sense as well as a 'stative' sense. They mean different things and each may be suitable according to context.

[Grammar Logs](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/grammarlogs/grammarlogs125.htm) seems to think either is fine: *I don't think there's anything particularly incorrect about "not understanding"; it's just silly.*

Comment: Reading the source quotation, it might be that *I am not understanding you* is actually a predicative adjective sentence rather than a present progressive with *not understanding you* functioning as an adjectival modification of I.

Comment: @virmaior +1 Technically, yes. However, the semantics have some problems.

Answer (score 1):

C is definitely wrong.  As you said,"understand" is a stative verb that should not be used in a progressive sense (though often is conversationally).

Comment: You can replace D with "following". How would you fix the sentence by replacing C?

Comment: @PeterShor "I'm" -> "I do"

Comment: In a similar vein, you could "fix" the sentence by replacing C with "This grammatical error in your phrasing confused me: "

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I will be able to provide a source to substantiate this answer, but the two sentences have the same essential meaning **but** differ in tone.

Grammatically, *I don't understand you* is the negative simple present tense indicative.  *I'm not understanding you* is the negative present progressive indicative. Progressive tenses can have multiple meanings, but in this case, they have the same meaning.

---

The difference, at least as I see it, is where the two forms place the failure of understanding. *I don't understand* places the failure on your side -- failure to provide something I could understand. *I'm not understanding* places the failure in understanding on my side, implying I must lack something necessary for understanding. implies that I am experiencing a type of cognitive failure that prevents understanding. In other words, the present progressive identifies an I-state *I am ... * whereas *I don't understand* is merely a negation of the state of understanding...

Comment: Oh, wait! I'm not understanding you.

Comment: @Kris tried to rewrite the unclear part...

Comment: Relax, that comment was just a pun!

Answer (score -1):

C is wrong since it's not a word. It's two!

Comment: Thanks, but this only half-answers the question. You've identified one of the three answers that is wrong without explaining what the correct one would be and why.

Comment: @choster: Yeah, sorry. It was just a lame joke, but I couldn't resist. I suppose I like to joke about these type of multiple questions since they in my experience usually are open to interpretation, usually unbeknownst to the writer of the question. I lost many point in school this way, and apparently it made me resentful to this day :)